# How to set location for folder of type FileFolder to another system

Tags: set, location, directory

1. I have one folder of type File Folder.

[image: Folder Properties]

2. I want to set Location to Another server like below for same folder
   [image: Folder Properties]

How can I set the location of a specific folder to another system

Answer (score 0):

Use mklink command

Example: mklink /D link target